# How to cancel Operation Queue with a for loop and dispatch_after inside with a growing delay

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

I have an OperationQ and for loop inside this. inside this for loop Im calling dispatch_after the delay is growing whenever the for loop iteration happen. this is to make sure the thing happen inside for loop will happen with a delay and sequentially.

Now when I want to reset this OperationQ with new data. Im cancelling all operations of the operationQ. this cancel the operation but the dispatch after thrown with a dispatch timer still running. is there a w ay I can cancel the dispatch_after inside the operationQ?

```
 OperationQ addoperationWithBlock({
  mainQ addOperationwithBlock({
   // Do some UI work
  delayCOnstant
  for (iteration)
  {
   delay += delayCOnstant
   dipathTime = dispatch_timeNow + delay
   dispatch_after(time, mainQ, 
   {
      // UI Drawing, dispatch after will draw smoothly and sequence
   })
  } 
  })
})
```

When i cancel the OperationQ the operation stops but the dispatch_after is still running with the dispatch_time we have given. Any ideas or suggestions

Answer (score 1):

`dispatch_after` has no cancel mechanism.  Being able to cancel is one of the advantages of `NSOperationQueue`.  So instead of doing the work directly in your `dispatch_after` block, use that block to schedule an `NSOperation` which can then also be cancelled.

Comment: But the problem I'm having is that I have to cancel the operation before the schedule time. OpQ->Dispatch->wait-schedule(during this schedule wait I may get interrupt to cancel this. if not my operation has to wait and run)->Operation

Answer (score 0):

As Curmudgeonlybumbly mentioned I used the NSOperation. but the thing i missed was once the operation started cancel was not doing anything. I have an iteration inside the operation. so i checked for self.cancelled and return. that worked. Thanks